# How can I have a shared Clippy configuration for all the crates in a workspace?

Tags: rust, rust-clippy

I have an application split into several crates. I want to deny or allow a specific lint in all crates. For example:

```rust
#![deny(clippy::print_stdout)]
```

It seems I have to add this to lib.rs in each of the crates.

There is an [ticket with Cargo](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/5034) to allow configuring this somehow, but it has been open for several years with no clear conclusion.

Is there a workaround to avoid having these allow/deny/warn lines duplicated per crate?

One idea I had was to `include!` the lines by creating a `clippy_config.rs` at the workspace root, then in each crate's lib.rs adding

```rust
include!("../../clippy_config.rs");
```

However this fails with

```
error: an inner attribute is not permitted in this context
 --> app/src/../../clippy_config.rs:1:1
  |
1 | #![deny(clippy::print_stdout)]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: inner attributes, like `#![no_std]`, annotate the item enclosing them, and are usually found at the beginning of source files. Outer attributes, like `#[test]`, annotate the item following them.
```

My other thought to use a macro [also does not work](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/6625#issuecomment-765851728) for much the same reason.

Is there a simple way to do this, except writing an external script to modify the Rust files to automate the duplication? (as mentioned [in this comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/6625#issuecomment-795700641) describing Embark Studio's setup).

Answer (score 18):

#### From Rust 1.74 onwards

Rust and Clippy lints can be configured:

- In Cargo.toml, see below.
- With attributes: `#[deny(clippy::print_stdout)]`.
- With flags: `-Dclippy::print-stdout`.

The configuration in `Cargo.toml` can be done in several ways.

For an individual crate, using the [`[lints]` section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-lints-section):

```ini
[lints.rust]
unsafe_code = "forbid"

[lints.clippy]
enum_glob_use = "deny"
```

For a workspace crate, using the [`[lints]` table](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/cargo/reference/workspaces.html#the-lints-table):

```ini
[workspace]
members = [...]

[workspace.lints.rust]
unsafe_code = "forbid"
```

Then in **each** crate in the workspace which wishes to inherit:

```ini
[lints]
workspace = true
```

*Note: when using `cargo new` to create a new crate in an existing workspace, the `[lints]` section is automatically added.*

#### When to use which?

**Attributes** are best used for one-off situations. For example, I regularly use `#[allow(clippy::too_many_arguments)]` on internal functions, but I wouldn't want it on public API functions.

**Cargo.toml** is best used for project wide settings which accommodate *both* the development workflow *and* CI. For example, I encourage the use of `unsafe_ops_in_unsafe_fn = "forbid"` so each unsafe operation safety pre-conditions are clearly documented, rather than a hand-wavy "trust me".

**Flags** are best used for workflow specific settings. For example, I would encourage `-Drust::dead-code` in CI, but it would be a pain during development.

#### Prior Versions

*(Also works in Rust 1.74 onwards, just possibly less convenient)*

Clippy offers 3 configuration modes:

- Attributes: `#[deny(clippy::print_stdout)]`
- Flags: `-Dclippy::print-stdout`
- Configuration file: `clippy.toml`, though restricted to a subset of configurable lints.

For project-wide configuration, across crates, the configuration file is the best option if it works.

Otherwise, the second best (hacky) option is to use flags *indirectly*. That is, rather than specifying `RUSTFLAGS=-Dclippy::print-stdout` in front of your compiler invocation, you can let Cargo do it, and configure Cargo project-wide.

At the root of your project, create a `.cargo/config.toml` file with the following content:

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-Dclippy::print-stdout"]
```

Cargo will then pass this flag to clippy when it invokes it.

*Note: in a workspace setting, `.cargo/config.toml` in individual crate folders is ignored when invoking Cargo from the root of the workspace, so best place this in the `.cargo` at the root.*

Comment: In a workspace setting, `clippy.toml` in the root of the workspace is (as of this writing) ignored when invoking `cargo clippy` from within the individual crate folder. I've worked around this by creating symlinks to `workspace_root/clippy.toml` in each crate folder.

Comment: Note only a small subset of clippy lints can be configured via `clippy.toml`.

Comment: you might consider using workspace-level configuration files.

Comment: @AdesojiAlu: Thanks for the reminder, I was excited for this new feature in 1.74 but completely forgot I had an answer that needed upgrading :)

Answer (score 4):

Starting from [Rust 1.74](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2023/11/16/Rust-1.74.0.html)(Released on 16-Nov-2023), [`Cargo.toml` supports `[lints]` table](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2023/11/16/Rust-1.74.0.html#lint-configuration-through-cargo) which you can use to configure the lints from the compiler and other tools.

```
[lints.clippy]
print_stdout = "deny"
```

Quoting from documentation:

> As proposed in `RFC 3389`, the `Cargo.toml` manifest now supports a
> `[lints]` table to configure the reporting level (`forbid`, `deny`, `warn`,
> `allow`) for lints from the compiler and other tools. So rather than
> setting `RUSTFLAGS` with `-F/-D/-W/-A`, which would affect the entire
> build, or using crate-level attributes like:
>
> ```
> #![forbid(unsafe_code)]
> #![deny(clippy::enum_glob_use)]
> ```
>
> You can now write those in your package manifest for Cargo to handle:
>
> ```
> [lints.rust]
> unsafe_code = "forbid"
>
> [lints.clippy]
> enum_glob_use = "deny"
> ```
>
> These can also be configured in a `[workspace.lints]` table, then
> inherited by `[lints] workspace = true` like many other workspace
> settings. Cargo will also track changes to these settings when
> deciding which crates need to be rebuilt.